# Imitate webserver for tests with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mockwebserver

I have a bit of a weird question: I have a program for scraping data from webpages (just the actual HTML pages, not API responses).

I need to write end-to-end tests for this program with the Jest library. In order to test the functionality consistently, I need to make sure that the referred web pages don't change, which would be almost impossible to achieve with resources on the web.

I wondered how good of a practice it is to spin up a new webserver locally with express/fastify/etc. to serve static HTML pages before running the tests and then shut the server down once the tests pass.

What I am looking for is a light web server with a single task - serve static html+css pages.
Are there any better ways to achieve what I mentioned? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We run `E2E` on our dev server `EG:- https://dev.something.com`, which is always up and running. Also as you said you could launch a lightweight webserver on `localhost` to run tests. But the only problem is When you do `E2E` using `CI/CD pipelines`, Then the test server can't access `localhost`. In that situation, you need a separate server to serve the site to the test server.

For now, If You are considering running tests on the local machine by launching and stopping a web server, I suggest you to use the `live server` extension in `visual studio code`. That is extremely lightweight and the best option to serve `HTML` and `asserts`. It will launch your site on `localhost`, Once your job is done, You can stop it with a button click.

[Live Server (VS Code Extension)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer)